# SSL Hosting Support for site with existing SSL certificate

Tags: web-hosting, php, https, security-certificate, heroku

I would like to know if there are any hosts that host PHP sites with SSL support for free, if I have an existing SSL certificate for my domain.

I checked out many questions here(about 10) but none of them have my specific requirement.

All questions are related to whether there are hosting sites that provide free SSL, however most sites do not since they have to pay for the certificate. Here, I have a valid certificate.

Heroku offers this custom certificate addon for $20, but I want to know if there are sites that offer it for free.

https://addons.heroku.com/ssl

[Please do not close this question since the requirement is different]

Comment: Possible duplication of http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements - please note just because your question may vary slightly doesn't mean its not duplicate.. Additionally if you cant find the answer in the post I posted its because no one has answered. For example someone can easily put an answer here is some free web hosts that support SSL... So your question may be considered a duplication.....

Comment: There are possibly additional costs involved - do you already have a dedicated IP for instance? I suspect your question is likely to be closed because you are asking for a recommendation which is generally off-topic as I understand it, not just because it might be a duplicate - but that duplicate is a generic "catch-all" for hosting-type recommendation questions.

Comment: @w3d oh, i didn't know that... i am actually looking for a site that offers the functionality.. and i don't really mind whether or not that site offers a dedicated ip. If SSL needs a dedicated ip, i suppose, than no hosts would offer it for free.

Comment: @w3d regarding the duplication, Then almost all recommendation questions in the hosting section could be marked as duplicate(!)